# mysql select in multiple fields

Tags: mysql

In my search I used autosuggest. The problem now is I have to search the value in multiple fields such as firstname,middlename,lastname,caption etc. How to identify that the match string will belong on specific field name.

let say i have table

```
 firstname     middlename     lastname      caption
 james         kelly          tow           handsome
 timy          john           fung          fearless
 hanes         bing           ken           great
```

in my input field once I typed "j" I should select and ouput

james
john
great

Currently I just output the firstname so instead of the above result I came out like below which is not good.

james
timy
hanes

It is possible? Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT IF(first LIKE 'j%',
          first,
          IF(middle LIKE 'j%',
             middle,
             IF(last LIKE 'j%',
                last,
                ''))) AS name
FROM mytable
HAVING name <> '';
```

Comment: hi max,

your solution is so nice and works for me. 

I tried before the fulltext search and using OR but the problem is I don't know in which fieldname belong. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just OR them together like so:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE firstname LIKE '%j%' OR lastname LIKE '%j%' -- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouts for a fulltext search.

Check out [the mysql entries about that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)!